# Set QMake Parameters in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qmake

I installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Qt 4.8.0 for VS2010 plus Qt VS Add-in 1.1.10 yesterday and still can't figure out how to:

1. Edit project (.pro) files from within Visual Studio.
2. Specify/modify QMake parameters for Debug and Release builds from within Visual Studio.

Can anyone please tell me how to do the above tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to try the documentation first. [Here is a link to the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/vs-add-in-1.1.7/vs-addin-managing-projects.html) of the Visual Studio add-in for managing Qt projects.

Comment: 1. Link is dead. 2. The update of the link doesn't answer the question.